# Check for installed RPM

Tags: chef-infra, rpm

In my cookbook I have:

```
unless app_rpm.nil?
  node.default['app_rpms'] = \
    %w(agent1 agent2 agen3 agent4)
  node['app_rpms'].each do |rpm_package|
    package rpm_package do
      action :remove
      not_if { "rpm -qa | grep -qx '#{node['agents']['agent']['type']['rpm_full_name']}'" }
    end
  end
end
```

However, despite defining "node['agents']['agent']['type']['rpm_full_name']" in the role with a correct value along the lines of agent-version.arch (e.g. *agent1-22.06-01.noarch*), on running ***rake unit*** I get:

> WARN: not_if block for yum_package[agent1] returned "rpm -qa | grep -qx ''", did you mean to run a command? If so use 'not_if "rpm -qa | grep -qx ''"' in your code

This happens for all the agents.

UPDATE:
I have amended the code to now have a separate line to create the command in a var. This is then referenced in the not_if. i.e.:

```
rpm_check_command = "rpm -qa | grep -qx '#{node['agent']['type']['rpm_full_name']}'"
not_if { rpm_check_command }
```

Now I am getting:

> WARN: not_if block for yum_package[agent1] returned "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'agent1-21.11.2-0.noarch'", did you mean to run a command? If so use 'not_if "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'agent1-21.11.2-0.noarch'"' in your code.

How do I make this into a command?

Comment: The single quotes around the node attribute `#{node['agents']['agent']['type']['rpm_full_name']}` will not allow for interpolation. Have you tried without them?

Comment: I've updated the code and now have a separate line to create the command. This is then referenced in the not_if.

i.e.:

    `rpm_check_command = "rpm -qa | grep -qx '#{node['agent']['type']['rpm_full_name']}'"
    not_if { rpm_check_command }`

Now I am getting:

> _WARN: not_if block for yum_package[agent1] returned "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'agent1-21.11.2-0.noarch'", did you mean 
to run a command? If so use 'not_if "rpm -qa | grep -qx 'agent1-21.11.2-0.noarch'"' in your code._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [examples](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/#not_if-examples) on the documentation page, curly braces are not required to run command for guards.

So, we should be able to write it as:

```rb
rpm_check_command = "rpm -q #{node['agent']['type']['rpm_full_name']}"

# ...
  node['app_rpms'].each do |rpm_package|
    package rpm_package do
      action :remove
      not_if rpm_check_command
    end
  end
# ...
```

Since you have the complete package name in the attribute I've omitted the `| grep` part. The `rpm -q <packagename>` command itself will return non-zero if a matching package is not found.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the curly braces has helped.

I had to add a stub_command into the spec too, apparently it is not allowed to run commands directly in rake unit.

Thanks again.